# Unity: Player can't move through multiple tilemaps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to game develpment and I'm learning Unity. Im making a 2D game and I have several tilesmap

[image]

- Water Tilemap: contains water sprites

[image]

- Background Tilemap: contains ground where player can move

[image]

- Over Ground Tilemap: contains flowers, mushrooms and other suff like this. Player can move on it.

[image]

- Climbing Tilemap: containst bridges and player can use them to walk across islands.

[image]

Now: my player get stuck on border of background tilemaps and cant move through Climbing Tilemap because (I think) he collide with background collision, what am i doing wrong? Can an object moving throug several tilemaps layers?
[Here a video demo](https://streamable.com/e/tu3162)